# Extrude individual showing pink lines when I extrude and won't repeat last steps when I press shift + R

Tags: modeling, extrude

Whenever I extrude an individual plane, it keeps showing pink lines and won't repeat last steps when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Are you sure an extrusion that moved some distance was the very last operation you performed and you didn't scale after or do some other minor modification?

Comment: The pink lines indicate a "Mean Crease". If you extrude them they are duplicated.

Comment: @Dontwalk I can't reproduce that. If you did perform a valid extrusion *with depth*, repeat last should do as the name implies. Care to explain more as an answer below if you're sure and can prove this? Also for beginners and newcomers, consider explaining how to disable or any workarounds as well, thanks.

Comment: @iKlsR - I created a plane > Edit Mode > Mean Crease to 1 (Creates the pink lines) > "E" to Extrude (Extrusion also has pink lines) > SHIFT "R" (Repeated Extrusion also has pink lines).

Comment: @Dontwalk Did you actually move the extrusion (add any depth to the plane) after pressing `E` by moving along the line generated along the face normal? If not it, the "extrusion" will just stay in place and nothing will appear to be done, hence this has nothing to do with creasing.

Comment: @iKlsR - I'm not providing an answer or asking a question. Simply providing a possible solution to the OP's "Pink Lines" statement. And yes I did preform the extrusion.  https://i.imgur.com/0klI7jp.png

Comment: @Dontwalk Ah ok, sorry, I missed that you were addressing a specific aspect. Thanks for clarifying.